# Collect data from 2 different tables, following conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

I have 2 MySQL tables. One is `pastsergicalhistory_type` and the other one is `pastsurgicalhistory`

Below is `pastsergicalhistory_type`

```
CREATE TABLE `pastsergicalhistory_type` (
 `idPastSergicalHistory_Type` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `idUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idPastSergicalHistory_Type`),
 KEY `fk_PastSergicalHistory_Type_User1_idx` (`idUser`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_PastSergicalHistory_Type_User1` FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`) REFERENCES `user` (`idUser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Below is `pastsurgicalhistory`

```
CREATE TABLE `pastsurgicalhistory` (
 `idPastSurgicalHistory` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `idPatient` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `idPastSergicalHistory_Type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Comment` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ActiveStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `LastUpdated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idPastSurgicalHistory`),
 KEY `fk_PastSurgicalHistory_Patient1_idx` (`idPatient`),
 KEY `fk_PastSurgicalHistory_PastSergicalHistory_Type1_idx` (`idPastSergicalHistory_Type`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_PastSurgicalHistory_PastSergicalHistory_Type1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPastSergicalHistory_Type`) REFERENCES `pastsergicalhistory_type` (`idPastSergicalHistory_Type`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_PastSurgicalHistory_Patient1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPatient`) REFERENCES `patient` (`idPatient`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now my requirement is as this, I will explain it in point form.

1. Get all the data from `pastsergicalhistory_type` where `idUser` is `NULL` or `idUser` is 1.
2. Get all the data from `pastsurgicalhistory` where `idPatient` is 2.

as you can see, the foreign key of `pastsurgicalhistory` is the primary key of `pastsergicalhistory_type`.

I tried the below query, but it gave me the wrong results. It only displayed what is available in `pastsurgicalhistory`. The data in `pastsergicalhistory_type` (which follows the condition in point 1) which is not in `pastsurgicalhistory` is not displayed.

```
 SELECT pastsergicalhistory_type.*,
    pastsurgicalhistory.*
    FROM pastsergicalhistory_type
    LEFT JOIN pastsurgicalhistory ON pastsurgicalhistory.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type` = pastsergicalhistory_type.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type`
    WHERE pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser = NULL OR pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser=1 AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2
```

So, how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

If I use the `AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2` in my where clause, it actually filters the "entire" result set. This will give me results where `idPatient` is related to 2. But as I mentioned, I need data which is not available in `pastsurgicalhistory` table as well.

Comment: Use parenthesis in your WHERE clause, that might be the reason you are getting unexpected results.. (A OR B) AND C. Also, your where has a condition on pastsurgicalhistory, probably that's why your are not getting all  rows in pastsergicalhistory_type

Comment: based on your recent edit, coudnt you do an `OR`? Some thing like (A `OR` B) `OR` pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2

Comment: @SoulTrain: No. It again wrong.

Comment: Provide sample data and the result you are getting in this case...

Comment: Do you get data from pastsergicalhistory_type - table if you don't have any where-statement at all?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: yes.

Comment: I agree with SoulTrain. Provide some sample data from both tables and tell us what you want to filter , I guess it would be easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  SELECT pastsergicalhistory_type.*,
    pastsurgicalhistory.*
    FROM pastsergicalhistory_type
    LEFT JOIN pastsurgicalhistory ON  
   (pastsurgicalhistory.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type` = 
      pastsergicalhistory_type.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type` and 
     pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2)
   WHERE (pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser = NULL OR
   pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser=1)  ;
```

Comment: If I use the `AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2` in my where clause, it actually filters the "entire" result set. This will give me results where `idPatient` is related to 2. But as I mentioned, I need data which is not available in `pastsurgicalhistory` table as well.

Comment: Then add AND
    pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2 inside left join condition like
(pastsurgicalhistory.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type` = 
      pastsergicalhistory_type.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type` and pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2)

Answer (score 0):

Use paraenthises?

```
WHERE pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser = NULL OR pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser=1 AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2
```

I belive would return results where idUser is 1 **and** idPatient is 2 **or** iduser is null

**Try this:**

```
WHERE (pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser = NULL OR pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser=1) AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2
```

**If I understand you correctly?**

```
SELECT pastsergicalhistory_type.*,
    pastsurgicalhistory.*
    FROM pastsergicalhistory_type
    RIGHT JOIN pastsurgicalhistory ON pastsurgicalhistory.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type` = pastsergicalhistory_type.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type`
    WHERE (pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser = NULL OR pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser=1) AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2
```

Even if it works without parenthesis for you, I would say it's better to use to make it more readable.

Comment: If I use the `AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2` in my where clause, it actually filters the "entire" result set. This will give me results where `idPatient` is related to 2. But as I mentioned, I need data which is not available in `pastsurgicalhistory` table as well.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean... but RIGHT JOIN  instead of LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Move `pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2` to join condition

```
SELECT pastsergicalhistory_type.*,
pastsurgicalhistory.*
FROM pastsergicalhistory_type
LEFT JOIN pastsurgicalhistory ON pastsurgicalhistory.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type` = pastsergicalhistory_type.`idPastSergicalHistory_Type`
                                 AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2
WHERE pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser IS NULL OR pastsergicalhistory_type.idUser=1
```

Comment: If I use the `AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2` in my where clause, it actually filters the "entire" result set. This will give me results where `idPatient` is related to 2. But as I mentioned, I need data which is not available in `pastsurgicalhistory` table as well.

Comment: move `AND pastsurgicalhistory.idPatient=2` to join condition. This way you  will filter only `pastsurgicalhistory` table.